# Web based JMX console for Glassfish?

Tags: glassfish, jmx

Following this question [JBoss AS 7 JMX Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702674/jboss-as-7-jmx-console) and [Web based JMX console for Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004958/web-based-jmx-console-for-tomcat) I wanted to Know what will be the best options for Glassfish?

Comment: Did you try using JMinix. It doesn't seem to have any bindings with tomcat and looks like it should work on Glassfish too - https://code.google.com/p/jminix/